# Silverlight + WCF Service with custom username/password

Tags: wcf, silverlight, passwords

We have a WCF service with custom username/password authentication.  The service runs over SSL.

On our existing WPF application we pass the username and password combination to the service every time it is called (i.e. we don't have any sessions with the service). The credentials are stored in memory on the client application.

Now we are looking at using Silverlight, and I'm thinking that storing the credentials in memory are going to pose a security risk.

What is the recommended advice for storing credentials when using a custom username/password service?

Thanks in advance
Matt

Comment: I don't understand why you think storing it in memory is a risk in a Silverlight application, as opposed to a WCF application - memory is still limited to the client machine. You may want to expand on that.

Comment: I think this is due to my lack of understanding of Silverlight.

I was of the understanding that keeping hold of credential information in web applications is a no-no.  Perhaps because the Silverlight application is installed into the local browser this is ok?

Comment: Both Silverlight and WPF run on the client side.  The only difference is that Silverlight can be hosted in a browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's a [security risk](http://www.infosecwriters.com/text_resources/pdf/Discovering_Passwords_In_Memory.pdf) in both WPF and Silverlight. In my app I'm planning to use [Authentication through message headers by implementing an operation behavior](http://kevindockx.blogspot.com/2009/02/username-authentication-with.html), but I'm going to pass a [token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627353/silverlight-wcf-login-session) rather than a username/password.